# C# - Quitting Selenium IWebDriver from Windows Form application

Tags: c#, user-interface, selenium

I am sorry if this is a dumb question. But I am a C# noob. I am trying to make a program where the user can selected which browser is used to execute a Selenium script.

I can successfully select my desired browser, hit the START button, and launch the correct browser. The program then performs a simple test action by navigating to a page.

What I want also want to be able to do is hit a STOP button and have the browser close. I have tried messing with the get; set; feature. But I don't think I have it quite right. Please note that I had removed my attempt at a get; set; configuration for the IWebDriver because it simply was not working, and I didn't want to confuse anyone.

Thanks

Here is my Windows Form:`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyInitializeComponent();
        }

        private readonly Browser form;
        public MainWindow(Browser form)
        {
            this.form = form;
        }

        //Initiate variables
        public string selectedBrowser;

        public string selBrowser
        {
            get { return comboBoxBrowser.Text; }
        }

        private void MyInitializeComponent()
        {
            //default values here
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Launch Browser
           Browser.ChooseDriver(selBrowser);
        }

                private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Perform the Quit operation on the Silenium driver
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainWindow());
        }

    }

    public class Browser
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver_;

        public IWebDriver driver
        {
            get { return _driver_; }
            set { _driver_ = driver; }
        }

        public static void ChooseDriver(string selBrowser)
        {
            //Run this if IE was selected
            if (selBrowser == "Internet Explorer")
            {
                RemoteWebDriver browserdriver = null;
                string serverPath = "Microsoft Web Driver";
                if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                {
                    serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%"), serverPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%"), serverPath);
                }

                InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                options.PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager;
                browserdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(serverPath, options);

                Launch(browserdriver);
            }
        }

        public static void Launch(RemoteWebDriver _driver)
        {
            //Set Page load timeout to 5 seconds
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            //Navigate to URL
            _driver.Url = "http://www.outlook.com/";
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Use _driver.Quit() or _driver.Close();

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can perform that function from with Program.cs - say once I am all done with navigating around and such. But I am trying to program in an additional way to quit the browser (STOP button). I don't have access to _driver in the windows form class. And I cannot figure out how to get it.

Comment: Does the form have access to the class Browser? If it does you can put an eventhanlder in Browser class to call _driver.Quit when the stop button is clicked.

Comment: I do not believe so. I *think* I have the Browser setup to have access to the form. Because the user is selected which browser they want to launch.
That selection is sent to the Browser class and the correct Selenium driver is configured. 

But I haven't been able to get access to work in the other direction. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You should move all your Browser code to be "contained" within the form so you have access to it.   In OOP this is "Favor composition over inheritance"  the Form will contain and instance of that class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John for your help on this. I was able to get all of my code running successfully within the form class. it was still bugging me that I could not figure out how to solve my original goal. So I kept looking for more examples and finally found the part that I was missing.

I was not instantiating the Browser class from within the Form class.

```
   private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser _browser = new Browser();
        _browser.GetBrowser(selBrowser); 
    }
```

I know it probably sounds like a simple mistake for someone to make, and easy to correct. But I've only been learning C# for a week or two, and the login behind doing that escaped me. Perhaps it still don't fully understand why or what i'm doing with this solution. But at least I can move forward.

And thanks to you as well Buaban. I will need that taskkill snippet to kill the console window that opens every time a selenium driver is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to separate code of the Form and the test, you can use these 2 options:

1. Use process.Kill()

   ```
   try
   {
       foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver.exe"))
       {
           proc.Kill();
       }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
   ```
2. Launch cmd taskkill

   ```
   System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   startInfo.Arguments = "/C taskkill /f /fi \"pid gt 0\" /im chromedriver.exe";
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   process.Start();
   ```